# What is the noun of Warn, warning someone

Tags: nouns

I'm wondering if it right to write : "I'm just a warner to you" and is there any (more) popular word to use referring to warning? Thank you!

Comment: There is the noun "warning", but it can't normally be used predicatively with human predicands.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. It would be unusual to say what you are trying to say, but see below for my answer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could say, 'I am a warning to you', but there is another word which I think is more used. I say 'more used' because it is archaic, but to say 'I am a warning' is also archaic so I should think it will not be a problem.

The word I have in mind is **portent**.

Portent : A sign, indication, or omen of a momentous or calamitous event which is about to happen.

[OED-3](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/148152?redirectedFrom=portent#eid)

The OED gives an instance of its use from 1981 :

> 1981   C. Francis Commanding Sea i. 8   Even after receiving a forecast and checking the barometer, I find I still search the sky for weather **portents**, just as sailors have done since the beginning of time.

It also gives a reference to a person being a portent, but this is older, 1921 :

> 1921   E. L. White Andivius Hedulio i. v. 86   You are..a **portent** in a fight.

and for this usage it shows the meaning to be a rarity :

> Portent 2. A prodigy, a wonder, a marvel; something exceptional or extraordinary. **Now rare.**

Comment: Thank you Nigel J, your answer is exactly what I was looking for. I think I'll be using the word *portent*, because I'm translating an old history book. Thanks again!

Comment: Nice and clear explanation. I do not know why your answer was down voted. Voting to remove the negative vote.

Comment: @starkeen It may be that it was felt to be a question below EL&U standard - a 'dictionary' question. But I felt it was not. There was more to it and I felt the unusual word 'portent' warranted an airing, so I took the risk. I shall delete if there is opposition. No problem.

Comment: I am not sure that warning or portent describes a person very well. It is somewhat awkward to say: I am a just portent to you. Usually, events are portents, not people....I would say: I am just the messenger or bringer of bad news....

Comment: @Lambie Perhaps that is why it became a rarity, although the OED documents that it was, and still can, be used. And the OP was translating a history book so the context appears to be appropriate.

Comment: The OED's citation for "you are ... a portent in a fight" has nothing to do with being a "warner". It means "marvel" or "prodigy" in that citation, a quite different use of the word.